# Issues predicting with `nlme::gls`quadratic model fitted with `poly(..., 2)`

Tags: r, nlme, poly

I have fitted a quadratic model with a variance structure that allows different variance levels per level of a factor, and I’m having trouble predicting on a new data set with 2 entries only. Here’s a reproducible example:

```r
library(nlme)
set.seed(101)
mtcars$amf <- factor(mtcars$am)
modGLS <- gls(mpg ~ amf*poly(hp, 2),
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1|amf), data = mtcars)
minhp <- min(mtcars$hp); maxhp <- max(mtcars$hp)
newdata <- data.frame(amf = as.factor(c(0, 1)),
                        hp = round(runif(2, min = minhp, max = maxhp)))
newdata2 <- data.frame(amf = as.factor(c(0, 0, 1)),
                        hp = round(runif(3, min = minhp, max = maxhp)))
predict(modGLS, newdata = newdata)
# Error in poly(hp, 2) : 'degree' must be less than number of unique points

predict(modGLS, newdata = newdata2)
## [1]  5.973306 13.758955 44.037921
## attr(,"label")
## [1] "Predicted values"
```

However, the prediction works well on an `lm` framework:

```r
modLM <- lm(mpg ~ amf*poly(hp, 2), mtcars)
predict(modLM, newdata = newdata)
##        1        2 
## 25.22253 16.83943
```

Why would that be? One of the package maintainers of `emmeans` seems to believe this may be related with missing information on `attr(, “predvars”)`
(see our discussion here https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/133)

I have reported this to Dr Bates (`nlme` point of contact) but thought I'd reach out to the wider community too.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Doug Bates is no longer the maintainer of nlme; now it's R-core. I will take a look at this, but it probably deserves to be a bug report (if it isn't already!)

Comment: By the way, I suspect that even when you don't get an error, the predictions are **wrong** when new data are provided (which is even worse).

Comment: In particular, there should be a "predvars" attribute in `terms(modGLS)`

Comment: Just added this: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18283

Comment: Your example can be simplified a lot ...

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker and @russ-lenth for your help and reporting the bug to R-core. I have simplified the example and provided an actual answer that explores the missing attribute from the GLS model object `terms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BenBolker and @russ-lenth for confirming that the issue is related to the missing `terms` attribute `"predvars"` in the GLS object, which provides the fitted coefficients for `poly`. Notice how this works in an LM framework (original post) and the attribute is there (see also `?makepredictcall`). Note that this can have potential implications for prediction.

```
## e.g. this fails
poly(newdata$hp, 2)
## but this is okay, because the polynomial has been estimated
polyFit <- poly(mtcars$hp, 2)
predict(polyFit, newdata = newdata$hp)

attr(terms(modLM), "predvars")
## list(mpg, amf, poly(hp, 2, coefs = list(alpha = c(146.6875, 198.071514938048), norm2 = c(1, 32, 145726.875, 977168457.086594))))

attr(terms(modGLS), "predvars")
## NULL
```

Comment: FYI, this bug has been fixed on `nlme` since mid March  2022